# How do I add CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS to my cabal file?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I can't seem to run `cabal install` on my project successfully, because it has as a dependency the the `text-icu` package, which needs the `icu4c` library installed on the system.

Well I installed `icu4c` on my Mac using `brew install icu4c`.

But `cabal install text-icu` still doesn't work because `brew install icu4c` installed the library in a place where the cabal build system can't find it. `brew info icu4c` gives me these special instructions:

```
This formula is keg-only, so it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

...

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include
```

So I need to tell cabal about these LDFLAGS and the CPPFLAGS. How do I do that in my cabal file?

*EDIT*

`brew link icu4c --force` seems to solve the problem. But I would still like to know the answer to the original question.

Comment: If you want it in the Cabal file: does it work when you use [ld-options and cc-options](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#build-information) in the `library` or `executable` sections in the Cabal file? Why you don't want it in the Cabal file: locating installed packages is up to the OS. How to do it alternatively: have you tried supplying these flags to `cabal` itself? (`LDFLAGS=blah CPPFLAGS=blah cabal install text-icu`?)

Comment: You're right, I don't want to hard code these paths in my cabal file.

Comment: `--extra-include-dirs=PATH` and `--extra-lib-dirs=PATH`?

Comment: I installed it by 

```cabal install --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/54.1/include --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/54.1/lib```

Note that both flags have to be specified. @Yuras, this is your answer with a successful build to back it up. I did not propose this as an answer, since you suggested it first.

Answer (score 3):

Homebrew gives you one directory for `CPPFLAGS` and another for `LDFLAGS`. We need to point the Haskell build system at these directories so it can find the appropriate header files to include and the appropriate libraries to link with.

## Pointing cabal at those paths

You can pass the needed info along to `cabal install` using some option flags like so:

```
cabal install \
    --extra-include-dirs=THAT_CPPFLAGS_DIR \
    --extra-lib-dirs=THAT_LDFLAGS_DIR \
    …
```

If you have multiple directories to provide, you can repeat the `--extra-XXX-dirs` flag to build up a list of directories one by one.

## Pointing stack at those paths

If you're using stack, then you can provide these options as part of your user configuration in `~/.stack/config.yml` by appending something like:

```
extra-include-dirs:
- /usr/local/opt/openssl/include
- /usr/local/opt/icu4c/include
extra-lib-dirs:
- /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
- /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib
```

This will apply to everything you `stack build` as that user, without your having to futz with flags on each command invocation.